# Can we pass an JSON to node js script from command line.?

Tags: node.js, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass a JSON to Node js script from command line. I have tried "JSON.parse" but it is giving error "Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1".

I have tried below things but no luck. Could someone please help. Here is my 'index.js'.

---

```
var args = process.argv;
var json = args[2];
console.log("JSON ::", json, "Type of JSON ::", typeof json);
console.log(
"JSON stringify ::",
JSON.stringify(json),
"Type of Stringify JSON ::",
typeof JSON.stringify(json)
);
```

---

From command line, I called the script with

---

```
node index.js "{'foo':'ball'}"
```

---

Here is the output :

---

```
JSON :: {'foo':'ball'} Type of JSON :: string
JSON stringify :: "{'foo':'ball'}" Type of Stringify JSON :: string
```

---

Type is showing as 'string'

Comment: JSON use Double quotes.

Comment: Tried that as well. No luck..